# Two variable Ehrhart polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, integer-lattices, polytopes

Is it possible to count the number of lattice points in a polytope that is scaled unevenly in two dimensions (or more generally mapped by some linear map) by some kind of two variable Ehrhart polynomial where we plug in the two different scale factors?